# Running C++ Programs with variable inputs

Tags: gcc, g++, runtime, variable-assignment

How to run a c++ code say (test.cpp) from command line as:

> ./solve l m

where l and m = input variable for test.cpp

solve is the object / Executable file for test.cpp.

I know that i can create a object file with

> g++ test.cpp -o solve

but how do i make

> **./solve l m**

work  ??

Comment: Are you reading from arg[1] and not arg[0]? Don't know much about it myself but I'm sure you read from the second index not the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main() takes two inputs. The first (argc) is the number of inputs (in your case 2, l and m), and it puts the two into a char* array (argv[]). So in main you'd do:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 
   cout << "argc = " << argc << endl; 
   for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) 
      cout << "argv[" << i << "] = " << argv[i] << endl; 
   return 0; 
}
```

Read parsing command line args here:http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~lucia/courses/2131-05/labs/Lab3/CommandLineArguments.html

Comment: I think this depends on the C runtime/platform you're running on. The first argument is usually the name of the program that's being run on most Unix systems, and it is for me, so argc is 1 when the program is run with no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything special to receive the parameters from the command line; both, I and m will be received in `**argv` in your main function

Answer (score 1):

You can pull out the "parameters" from the main function. You have to parse them and make sure they are in usable form for your program.

```
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
```

int argc -> amount of arguments
and the constant char* argv[] is the actual array of the arguments.
Note that the first argument is the name of the program.
Then all the other ones you wrote out in command line.

Answer (score 0):

In particular, `argc` contains the number of entries in `argv`. The first entry in `argv` is usually the name of the program, so you will want to check the elements after that one, provided that there are any. For more complicated programs, parsing the command-line arguments can be a pain. In this case, Boost.ProgramOptions may be of interest to you.

In order to get the size of each individual argument, you may find `strlen` in `cstdlib` to be helpful.